# Design of data accumulation while iterating a collection

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, collections, software-design

I have a big collection of elements.
I would like to iterate it and accumulate some specific values (let's say about 10 values).
I wonder if there is a good way to do it SW design wise.

I would like to accumulate the data and later create a final object that consists of the accumulated data (immutable object).
Is there a good design pattern for such purpose?

The "Builder" is not good here because I would like to change the values while iterating the collection.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [*Builder* design pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/builder-design-pattern-in-java.html) (I've linked one blog post but you can find plenty of information with Google).

This pattern is used when there are a lot of arguments in the constructors, which makes it cumbersome to invoke and maintain the constructor(s) in Java. It is especially used when you want to preserve invariants in the class that is being built (otherwise, it would be possible to configure the class using setter methods). One case in which this is true is when you have immutable objects, which is your case.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Builder. Though the builder doesn't actually accumulate data, it just let's you modify many fields before creating the final object. I want to modify the values while iterating the collection

Comment: @VitaliMelamud If you have a builder, you can modify the values in the builder object while you are iterating (you can add getter methods to the builder to facilitate this); and when you're done iterating, you can let the builder create the immutable object.

Comment: Do you think that getters in the Builder is a good idea? Didn't see this expansion anywhere

Comment: @VitaliMelamud with the risk of going into the "subjective" realm - I have done this on a couple of projects and it for these, it turned out fine - everyone understood it and there wasn't a problem maintaining such code.

Answer (score 1):

The builder pattern is what you're looking for. You store your accumulated data into a builder object and, when you're done, ask the builder to create the immutable object from everything it has accumulated.

Without a more concrete usecase from you, it's hard to give you a more concrete example.

But see this pattern in action [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.Builder.html), for example.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Builder. Though the builder doesn't actually accumulate data, it just let's you modify many fields before creating the final object. I want to modify the values while iterating the collection

Comment: The builder does whatever you want it to do. How could a builder for an ImmutableList, such as the one I linked to, work if it didn't accumulate all the elements of the immutable list to build?

Comment: The example is great indeed! But do you think it's a good idea to provide a user with an interface to modify the builder members after they were set - that is - let's say for an Integer member, let the user to add some value to it and also let him subtract from it...

Comment: If your use-case needs that functionality, and if you feel that's the best way to design this functionality, why not?